# Join 2 Tables with 2 conditions (MySQL and PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: users and prov_spec_search. Am looking for an sql query to join these tables with the following conditions:

```
users Table:

id | first_name | last_name | activ_status
-------------------------------------------
6  | sudha      | dravid    |    1
7  | Gokul      | menon     |    1
13 | sujith     | nair      |    1
-------------------------------------------
```

prov_spec_search Table

```
id | inv_user_id | drafter_id | activ_status
-------------------------------------------
1  | 13          | 7          |    1
2  | 13          | 6          |    1
-------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result is:

```
Need to join users and prov_spec_search tables with 2 conditions where 

prov_spec_search.inv_user_id = users.id = Name

      AND 

prov_spec_search.drafter_id = users.id = Drafter name
```

Result:

```
Name       |   Drafter Name   | Active
------------------------------------------
sujit nair |   Gokul menon    |  active
sujit nair |   sudha dravid   |  active
```

I have started with this query:

```
SELECT
prov_spec_search.id,
prov_spec_search.inv_user_id,
prov_spec_search.drafter_id,
prov_spec_search.activ_status,
users.first_name,
users.last_name,
users.activ_status AS activ_status1
FROM prov_spec_search
INNER JOIN users ON prov_spec_search.inv_user_id = users.id AND prov_spec_search.drafter_id = users.id
WHERE (prov_spec_search.activ_status ='1')
```

Comment: Hi Sanju, Could you please provide us with an example of what have you tried and what is going wrong with that? That'll enable us to help in a better manner.

Comment: I have updated the end of the question with an sql query which i tried. I am still a learner. so pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join from the `prov_spec_search` table to the `users` table, *twice*:

```
SELECT
    pss.id,
    pss.inv_user_id,
    pss.drafter_id,
    pss.activ_status,
    CONCAT(u1.first_name, ' ', u1.last_name) AS Name,
    CONCAT(u2.first_name, ' ', u2.last_name) AS Drafter_Name
FROM prov_spec_search pss
LEFT JOIN users u1
    ON pss.inv_user_id = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2
    ON pss.drafter_id = u2.id
WHERE
    pss.activ_status = 1;
    -- you may filter user and drafter names here if desired
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: nice answer, also I think he wanted a few where conditions (to be active, to filter the drafter name and to filter the user name)

Comment: yes i added those conditions. its all working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the `users` table twice: once for the `Name` and once for the `Drafter Name`:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(n.first_name, ' ', n.last_name) as Name,
    CONCAT(d.first_name, ' ', d.last_name) as Drafter_Name,
    p.activ_status as Active
    FROM prov_spec_search p
    JOIN user n ON p.inv_user_id = n.id
    JOIN user d ON p.drafter_id = d.id
    WHERE p.activ_status = 1
```

Note that I assume you get the status `Active = 1` from somewhere else, but I'm sure you can add that to the query above without any trouble.